# decimal representation of key chracters

Tags: c++

I'm not to familiar with C++ so when I was nosing through the source of a crackme, I got a little confused when it seemed like the short -223 or

`foo = 0xde;// 222 
unarfoo = ~(foo);// -223`

was being translated into the char "!" when I ran this line of code...

`cout << (char)(~(foo));// outputs "!"`

This obviously isn't an ascii translation since ascii doesn't use negative numbers for chars so I'm guessing this is something exclusive to the compilation of C, since when I tried translating any negative short/int into a char on java all I got was an "?".

Can anyone elaborate on what exactly is happening and why? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

0xde = 11011110b, ~(0xde) = 00100001b = 0x21 hex which in ASCII table stands for !

so ~ operator in c++ is a bitwise negation

Comment: Isn't that in html? I thought 0x33 equaled dec 51 or char 3

Comment: You mean 33 decimal, or 0x21 hex.

Answer (score 0):

Java is using UNICODE (64-bit values) for characters so when you try a -233 it ends up somewhere near the top part of the UNICODE table and is most likely cannot be represented on your system.

The program you saw in C was using a `char` datatype which is 8-bit wide. So a ~(-233) is pretty much the same (bit-wise) as a 33 (or the `!` character)

Comment: actually java char type is 2 byte long, and java is using UTF-16. Its not using 64-bit characters.

Comment: So as anatolyg stated above 

~foo is 0xffffff21;

(char)~foo is 0x21 (the exclamation mark)

So bit wise... If i'm understanding this right... the first 6 F hexes are being truncated... or ignored leaving just 0x21 which would be 33 or the ! mark?

Comment: Alright I'm going to assume this is right though I can't test it for myself on a C compiler atm.

Thought when I tried it in java I got these results which interested me. 

`System.out.println(result - 0);//65313
  
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(result));//ff21`

it seems only the first 4 F hexes were truncated which would explain why I didn't get 0x21

Comment: forgot this snippet of code for context o.o
`char result = (char)(~(foo));` foo = 0xde

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is 0xde or 0x000000de;

`~foo` is 0xffffff21;

`(char)~foo` is 0x21 (the exclamation mark)

Comment: Forgot its proper name; fixed now

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is how the processor handles two's complement operation AND negative numbers. The case is that they're the same: since characters are almost everytime 8-byte, what you get is:

foo = 222;
   unarfoo = ~foo = -(255 - foo) = - (255 - 222) = -233

So essentially it's just a matter of interpreting a char as signed or unsigned.